# Trying to Adjust z-index so that lightbox covers entire browser screen

Tags: css, z-index, lightbox

I recently found an article that gave me code to create a lightbox effect. Here's the article: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

I realize this article was written in 2007, so maybe his explanation is no longer relevant.

Here's the problem, I have used his codes to create the lightbox effect, and tweaked them according to my needs. The only problem is, the "black overlay" section does not reach to the bottom of the browser.

In the article mentioned above, he explained that his code was supposed to create it so that the black overlay extended the entire width and height of the browser window and referenced the z-index to demonstrate this, but this is not the case for the height.

I have tried adjusting the z-index to be more than what it originally was, but nothing has worked so far. I've also tried searching for solutions, but again nothing I've tried has worked. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the black overlay to reach the bottom of the browser window? I tried this on a smaller screen (15") as well as mine (17") but the issue still remains. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Here is a rough [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L39De/) and corresponding code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="random-element">
        <div class="fade"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="random-element"></div>
    <div class="random-element"></div>
    <div class="random-element"></div>
    <div class="random-element"></div>
    <div class="random-element"></div>
    <div class="random-element"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffe;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.random-element {
    margin: 50px 0 0 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #aff;
}

.fade {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code, or set up a jsfiddle.  Links to sites are no good, because when this problem is solved, or the site is gone, this question (and it's answers) will no longer be useful.

Comment: Additionally, the reason that this isn't working has nothing to do with z-index.  Rather, it's because your `fade` element is a child of a div, when it needs to be a direct child of the `body` in order for your `height: 100%` to work.  Note that you would be able to see / find this fairly quickly if you were to take advantage of debugging tools such as Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS from absolute positioning to fixed positioning.

```
.fade {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Don't encourage bad questions like this with an answer.  This question as-is will get closed, and won't be useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't really think about that.

Comment: Hi, all. Thanks so much for the explanation, question suggestion, and answer. I'm still new here and learning the best ways to post questions, so I will most certainly adjust my question so that it's better for the community. Your answer worked perfectly, and I'll mark it as such. Please forgive my lack of knowledge and I'll definitely work to make my questions more beneficial in the future.